# Displaying read-only forms (values are shown as text instead of disabled input controls) with JSF?

Tags: jsf, uiview, readonly

I have a data entry form where user enters lots of data. When user comes to the page to view existing data, the page should be displayed in read-only mode (all values shown as text), when he clicks 'Edit' button, normal form with all input controls should be shown so that user can change and save data.

We are using JSF 2.0 with PrimeFaces library. It is easy to achieve above behavior for text box and text area but not for Checkbox, multi-select, radio,..... controls. Is there any easy way available to achieve above behavior rather than writing our own code (which may run into lot of lines thus making backing bean code ugly)

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think that you need additional backing bean code for this. You've all the  needed values in the backing bean already. Your problem is more in the presentation of those values. Just display them in the desired format by writing the view code accordingly. Perhaps you were thinking it too the hard way.

Instead of a select boolean checkbox, you could display for example a "Yes" or "No" value.

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.checked}" rendered="#{bean.edit}" />
<h:outputText value="#{bean.checked ? 'Yes' : 'No'}" rendered="#{not bean.edit}" />
```

Instead of a select one menu/radio, you could just display the value in an output text.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedItem}" rendered="#{bean.edit}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{data.availableItems}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:outputText value="#{bean.selectedItem}" rendered="#{not bean.edit}" />
```

Instead of a select many listbox/checkbox, you could just display for example all values comma separated in a loop.

```
<h:selectManyListbox value="#{bean.selectedItems}" rendered="#{bean.edit}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{data.availableItems}" />
</h:selectManyListbox>
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not bean.edit}">
    <ui:repeat value="#{bean.selectedItems}" var="selectedItem" varStatus="loop">
        #{selectedItem}#{not loop.last ? ', ' : ''}
    </ui:repeat>
</h:panelGroup>
```

You could wrap it all in a tag file or a composite to minimize boilerplate and code repetition.

Comment: When the control's label is not equal to it's value, it is not that straight forward.

Comment: For example, for a select boolean checkbox, the values displayed to the user are 'Male' and 'Female'. On selection either 'M' or 'F' will be stored in database based on user's selection. In this case in view mode, to display either 'Male' or 'Female', additional backing bean code must be written to convert database value into user presentable text. Same will be the issue with other controls as well. For the above approach to work, control's label must be equal to value, which will not be in most of the cases. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: You've those values already in the data behind `<f:selectItems>`. Just access and print them accordingly. In the future just ask a question straight to the point like as you did in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in my last project using composite components which has a "preview" attribute and in the implementation I render a text when this attribute is true and the real (editing) when the attribute is false. For checkbox in preview mode you could show the checkbox itself but disabled, for radio - show the selected item.

MyFaces Tomahawk library [1] contains an extended version of the standard components that adds displayValueOnly attribute for this purpose. This might help you (I haven't used them).

[1] - http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/index.html