# session scope bean - how to handle multi user data

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, javabeans, session-scope

Well I have created a web application using JSF 2.0. Everywhere I have used **session scope bean** and because of that I am facing problem. :( I will explain with below example.

I have list of users in dataTable. When I click on user, I see details of that user. Now when I right click on User A and click `Open in new tab`, I see details of User A in in new tab.

Now when I right click on User B and click Open in new tab, I see details of user B.

However when I go on tab (where user A details are there), and refresh that page, I see User B details.

How to overcome that so that if I refresh page, I will still see details of User A and not User B.

Comment: What you did is a very classic anti-pattern ;) Exactly this inspired the view and conversation scopes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the bean in the view scope instead.

When opening the details page, you should send a GET request, not a POST request. Use a normal `<h:link>` which passes the user identifier along as a request parameter by `<f:param>` and have a converter in the target view to convert it to the proper model value.

The session scope should be used for session scoped data only, such as logged-in user and its preferences.

#### See also:

- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)
- [Creating master-detail pages for entities, how to link them and which bean scope to choose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459903/jsf-application-correct-use-of-session-scope/8464636#8464636)