# How can I know the button which sends the click event from jsf data table

Tags: jsf

I have the following table

```
<f:view>
                <h:form>
                    <h1><h:outputText value="List"/></h1>
                    <h:dataTable value="#{groupBean.groups}" var="item" >
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Id"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:button value="#{item.id}" />
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Name"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/>
                        </h:column>
                    </h:dataTable>
                </h:form>
            </f:view>
```

and I want to use this button

```
 <h:button value="#{item.id}" />
```

to know the selected item from the list

I want to get the item.name and add it to edit text in the same page , how can I do that ?

Comment: The `h:button` will just go to a new URL (or reload the page), are you sure that is what you want. Anyway, with other types of input (like `h:commandButton`), the usual way is a nested `f:param` attribute.

Comment: ok can you give me example

Comment: What is the requirement of your code? Do you know that `<h:button>` will generate a plain 'JavaScript GET-style' button used for navigational purposes. You seem to expect that some server-side action can be called, which is wrong. Also, there are many ways to achieve the latter functionality.

Comment: Please don't confuse JSP with JSF or Facelets. I removed the inappropriate JSP tag from the question. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095397/what-is-the-difference-between-jsf-servlet-and-jsp/2097732#2097732

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the item as request parameter.

```html
<h:button value="#{item.id}">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{item.id}" />
</h:button>
```

You can set it in bean of target page via `<f:viewParam>`.

#### See also:

- [Creating master-detail pages for entities, how to link them and which bean scope to choose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459903)
- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798)
- [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in java script.
Put an `id` attribute to the specific tag. 
and get the item.name

jsf code:

```
<h:outputText value="#{item.name}" id="ItemName"/>
```

js code:

```
  var name = document.getElementById("ItemName");
  var nameValue = name.value;
```

`name`  will get a reference to the element. 
nameValue will get the value of the element.

Comment: You might be unfamiliar with JSF, so I wouldn't post the answer 'as is' in your place. To the very least, JSF prepends ids within a `<h:form>` with the provided id, or the autogenerated id (this case). So for your code to work you need to search for an element whose id *ends with* the specified value.