# passing value while using view scope in jsf

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, javabeans, view-scope

I have a table with few rows and one of the columns consists a button,now when i click on the edit button it takes me to a new JSF page.The details in the edit page are not getting populated.I am using view scope for my Managed Bean.I have gone through some of the posts and understood that view scope will be lost once the user leaves from that page.

I have gone through various other posts which suggested me to pass value to another bean and then get it into new jsf or by using f:viewparam. I wanted to know how i could achieve this functionality:

I want this flow to be achieved using view scoped managed bean JSF1-->on click of edit button in table-->View Scoped Managed Bean-->JSF2(details need to be populated but shows null values)

In the edit details page the value is shown null.

Could you let me know how I can achieve this functionality.Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Correct usage of session scope in two-page master-detail user interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459903/correct-usage-of-session-scope-in-two-page-master-detail-user-interface)

Comment: Your concrete mistake is by the way that you used POST instead of GET for the navigation from master page to detail page.