# Clicking on a row opens a new link, based on what was clicked

Tags: jsf

I am new to JSF, and I tried Googling this and going over BalusC's example, but failed. I have a datatable right now, which works, but what I want to acheive is that when you click on a row, I want to store some information in a bean of course, and then open a new page where I can display some more detail about the row that was clicked. Here is my code:

```
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5">  

          Degree: 

          <div class="degreeProgram">
    <h:selectOneMenu onchange="submit()" valueChangeListener="#{course.degreeProgramChanged}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{course.programs}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
           </div>
             Major:

             <div class="major">
            <h:selectOneMenu onchange ="submit()" valueChangeListener="#{course.majorChanged}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{course.majors}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
             </div>
             Identifier:
             <h:inputText value="#{course.identifier}"></h:inputText>

              Course coordinator:

             <div class="major">
              <h:selectOneMenu onchange ="submit()" valueChangeListener="#{course.coordinatorChanged}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{course.coordinators}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
             </div>

            </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>  



             <b>Course Offering:</b>
            <br></br>


            <h:form>

        <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5">  

          Section: 

          <div class="degreeProgram">
              <h:inputText value="#{course.section}"></h:inputText>

           </div>
             Semester

             <div class="major">
                 <h:inputText value="#{course.semester}"></h:inputText>

             </div>

              Instructors:
             <div class="major">
                 <h:selectOneMenu onchange ="submit()" valueChangeListener="#{course.coordinatorChanged}">
                     <f:selectItems value="#{course.instructors}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
             </div>

              <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{course.executeSearch()}"></h:commandButton>

             </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
```

Comment: @BalusC please give me a hand here. You are the only expert I know.

Comment: The code isn't making much sense. I'm not seeing a data table. I'm only seeing a panel grid. I'm not seeing any links, only a lot of change listeners and a submit button. I'm not sure what to say here. This is perhaps helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459903/correct-usage-of-session-scope-in-two-page-master-detail-user-interface/8464636#8464636