# How to remove element from datatable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

A simple application that uses Primefaces [datatables with radio button selection](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml) doesn't behave properly. 
When I choose an element with radio button, the `event` argument is `null` in `delete()` method, therefore the selected row can't be removed from the datatable.

**view.xhtml** // *Here is where I get problems*

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Event List</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:dataTable id="eventlist" var="event" value="#{eventBean.eventlist}" selection="#{eventBean.selectedEvent}" rowKey="#{event.id}" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="200" style="width:500px;">
            <f:facet name="header">
                Event List
            </f:facet>
            <p:column selectionMode="single" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>
            <p:column headerText="ID">
                <h:outputText value="#{event.id}">
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Date">
                <h:outputText value="#{event.date}">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            <f:facet name="footer">

                <p:commandButton process="eventlist" action="#{eventBean.delete(eventBean.event)}" value="#{eventBean.event}" ajax="true" >

                </p:commandButton>
            </f:facet>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

**EventBean.java** // *This is my managed bean*

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean
@Named(value = "eventBean")
@RequestScoped
public class EventBean {

@EJB
private EventManager em;

private Event event;

private Event selectedEvent = new Event(); 

private Date currentDate;

private List<Event> eventlist = new ArrayList<Event>();


public Date getCurrentDate() {
    if (currentDate == null) {
        currentDate = new Date();
    }
    return currentDate;
}

public EventBean() {
}

public Event getEvent() {
    if (event == null) {
        event = new Event();
    }
    return event;
}

public void setEvent(Event event) {
    this.event = event;
}

public List<Event> getEventlist() {
    return eventlist;
}

public void setEventlist(List<Event> eventlist) {
    this.eventlist = eventlist;
}

public Event getSelectedEvent() {

    return selectedEvent;
}

public void setSelectedEvent(Event selectedEvent) {
    this.selectedEvent = selectedEvent;
}

public String create() {
    em.save(event);
    eventlist = em.findEvents();
    return "view";
}

public String delete(Event event){  //the event object is null
    em.deleteEvent(event);
    return "index";
}
}
```

Briefly, what I would like to achieve is: select properly the row from the datatable and then delete it both from the datatable and database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selection is set as `#{eventBean.selectedEvent}`, but you're passing `#{eventBean.event}` forth and back to the delete method. This problem is two-fold. Firstly, it's the wrong property. Secondly, you don't need to pass it forth and back. It's already in the bean.

So, this should do:

```
<p:commandButton ... action="#{eventBean.delete}" />
```

with

```
public String delete() {
    em.deleteEvent(selectedEvent);
    return "index";
}
```

Another strange thing is that you're nowhere initializing the `eventlist` during bean's initialization. This means that when you submit the form, during that new request wherein the request scoped bean is newly constructed and initialized, the `eventlist` would be `null` and thus there would be nothing available to select and set in the model.

You should have the following method in `EventBean`:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    eventlist = em.findEvents();
}
```

This way you should now also be able to see the list already when just directly opening the `view.xhtml` in browser without first submitting an arbitrary form in another page. In other words, it's now finally [idempotent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-make-url-reflect-the-current-page-and-not-the-previous-one/15523045#15523045).

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you're mixing JSF and CDI bean management annotations. Get rid of the `@ManagedBean` annotation altogether. You're also performing lazy loading in getter methods. Get rid of them all and do the job in `@PostConstruct` and leave the autogenerated getter (and setter) methods untouched. This way you can also easily provide more short code snippets in questions where by you omit all getters/setters, because they are obvious enough.

Comment: I tried to modify the code as you suggested but I got this log:


    Alert: A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB    EventManager, method: public void boundary.EventManager.deleteEvent(entity.Event)
    Alert: javax.ejb.EJBException

[...]

    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy244.deleteEvent(Unknown Source)
    at boundary.__EJB31_Generated__EventManager__Intf____Bean__.deleteEvent(Unknown Source)
    at control.EventController.delete(EventController.java:86)

[...]

    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: null is not a known entity type.

[...]

Comment: It's not visible in your code how you're preparing and preserving the `eventlist`. It's basically an empty list which I assumed to be result of oversimplification of the code. Try posting a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: In the original text of the question there were all the created files of the project except for the entity Event.java. However, the variable List<Event> eventlist is only for showing the data in the datatable purpose and not for the the delection of the event, to which I assigned the variable Event selectedEvent. I think my main problem now is that selection="#{eventBean.selectedEvent}" doesn't get the selected event.

Comment: You should be doing `eventlist = em.findEvents();` in `@PostConstruct` of the bean and preferably make the bean `@ViewScoped`.

Comment: I think @PostConstruct is not my problem because I actually can see the whole list of the stored data. 
But anyway I tried your method but if I use ViewScoped I get EJBException when I create and show the list of events (and this was the part that used to work).

Comment: As of now, your list view cannot exist without create view. This isn't right. You should be able to open the list view standalone. See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459903/creating-a-master-detail-user-interface-for-entities-which-bean-scope-to-choose/8464636#8464636

Comment: It works! :) At the end I've added the `@PostConstruct` as you suggested and mantained the `@RequestScoped` annotation. However I changed the method by passing the value of the id of the event instead of the event itself. Thanks!