# Output and Command Link in one in JSF

Tags: jsf, hyperlink, action

Is there a possibility to use both outcome and action in the same command link?

I tried

```
    <h:commandLink  outcome="page?faces-redirect=true" 
value="Got to Page" 
action="#{Bean.setValue("...")}" />
```

but it ignores the outcome.

I have a table with data like this:
ID     Name      Other Things      Link to Next Page

So I want to give the ID to the next page to show data which belongs to the selected ID from before... How could I realize this?

Comment: An `<h:commandLink>` does not have the `outcome` attribute. Where did you get that it has?

Comment: It does no say 'error' - so I tried to use it as in OutcomeLink...

Comment: Use `<h:outputLink>` instead, pass that identifier (using `<f:param>`), receive the parameter  on the target page (using `<f:viewParam>`) and fetch the data based on the identifier in the corresponding managed bean.

Comment: Why not pass the page in the action as well and do the redirect in the method you call? Or combine it with an actionlistener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `<f:setPropertyActionListener>`.

```
<h:commandLink value="Edit" action="edit?faces-redirect=true">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.id}" value="#{id}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Or you could abuse `actionListener`.

```
<h:commandLink value="Edit" action="edit?faces-redirect=true" 
    actionListener="#{bean.setId(id)}" />
```

Both ways, however, would require a session scoped bean to remember the chosen `id`, which is plain awkward. When you open such link multiple times in different browser tabs and then interact on each them afterwards, the site's behavior would be really unintuitive and confusing.

The canonical way is to just pass it as a GET parameter.

```
<h:link value="Edit" outcome="edit">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{id}" />
</h:link>
```

The target page can get hold of it via `<f:viewParam>` and if necessary invoke business action on it via `<f:viewAction>`.

#### See also:

- [Creating master-detail pages for entities, how to link them and which bean scope to choose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459903/creating-master-detail-pages-for-entities-how-to-link-them-and-which-bean-scope/)