# Request scope bean command button - Passing parameter

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, parameters, facelets, commandbutton

I have a request scoped JSF 2 backing bean corresponding to a facelet. The facelet has a command button that calls another JSF 2 request scoped backing bean.

When I click on the commandbutton, is there a way to not call the first bean's constructor and post constructor? If that is not possible with a request scoped bean, can I use h:link or something similar to invoke the action method in secondBean? Also, how do I pass the parameter in the action method below (as the ELs cannot be nested)

```
<h:outputText value={firstBean.variable1.variable2} />

<p:commandButton action="#{secondBean.actionMethod(firstBean.variable1.variable2)}" ajax="false" value="Move Forward" />
```

Comment: Is this acceptable as dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/q/8459903

Comment: @BalusC hi Balusc, even if it is a ViewScoped bean and if I follow your pattern as mentioned in the link above, will the ViewScoped bean coverter get called again if the details page has a different backing bean?

Comment: Not if it's a GET link as shown in the example. Have you tried it?

Comment: @BalusC, I am talking about the /products/edit.xhtml page. Once the page loads initially, the constructor is called. However, after I click on the "Edit" button, since it is a command button that fires a post request, the Constructor (and PostConstruct) will be called again? Why would we need that?

Comment: Did you miss the fact that the example bean in question is `@ViewScoped`? I cite: *"the bean should preferably be view scoped"*. See also the 1st link "How to choose right bean scope" over there.

Comment: @BalusC, thanks for the answer. Please mark it as a duplicate, thanks