# JSF send Date via POST

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have JSF project where I have an `overview.xhtml` page and a `detail.xhtml` page.

On the `overview.xhtml` page I have table with entries, like this

```
+-----------------+----------------+
|    2015/09/09   |     edit       |
|    2015/01/02   |     edit       |
+-----------------+----------------+
```

Now when the user clicks on `edit` the `detail.xhtml` page should be shown along with the date from column 1 as parameter.
parameter because I don't want to format the date. Would it be a good idea to use POST to send the parameter? Thus I could send the plain Java `java.util.Date` object to the new page.

Would I have any drawbacks I am not thinking of?

Comment: Is this acceptable as dupe to your XY problem? http://stackoverflow.com/q/8459903

Comment: hm... Would I have any drawbacks beside the fact of bookmarkable ?