# <h:link> vs <h:commandLink> in <h:dataTable>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, hyperlink, datatable, commandlink

When I want to see the detail page of my Book I will get my book and redirect it to my overviewpage. Now when I use the `<h:link>` he always gives the last item of my dataTable. When I use the `<h:commandLink>` everthing works fine. Now my question, why doesn't work the `<h:link outcome="...">` when the 'same' code in `<h:commandLink>` will work?

Managed Bean

```
@Named(value = "bookController")
@SessionScoped
public class BookController implements Serializable {

@EJB private BookRepository dao;
private LibraryBook book = new LibraryBook();

...

public String getLibraryBook(String isbn)
{
    this.book = this.dao.getBook(isbn);
    return "bookOverview";
} 

...

}
```

Book.xhtml

```
<f:view>
        <h:form>
            <h:dataTable value="#{bookController.books}" var="item" class="table">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Isbn"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:link value="#{item.isbn}" outcome="#{bookController.getLibraryBook(item.isbn)}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Title"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.title}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <h:commandButton value='Update' class="btn btn-warning" action="#{bookController.EditBook(item)}"></h:commandButton>
                    <h:commandButton value='Delete' class="btn btn-danger" action="#{bookController.deleteBook(item.isbn)}"></h:commandButton>
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </f:view>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `<h:link outcome>` is evaluated at the moment the page is rendered, not when you click the link. The method you're referring in `outcome` sets the session scoped bean property to the current item and then returns a string `bookOverview`. So, effectively you end up with every single link having a `outcome="bookOverview"` before you click on it. In the meanwhile, the bean has only the last item remembered.

The `<h:commandLink action>` works because it is evaluated after you click the link.

This difference is because `<h:link>` is intented for idempotent (GET) requests which does not require a stateful `<h:form>`, and the `<h:commandLink>` is intented for non-idempotent (POST) requests which require a stateful `<h:form>`.

#### See also:

- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)
- [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-navigate-in-jsf-how-to-make-url-reflect-current-page-and-not-previous-o)

---

That said, the real problem you're trying to solve is answered here: [Creating master-detail pages for entities, how to link them and which bean scope to choose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459903/creating-master-detail-pages-for-entities-how-to-link-them-and-which-bean-scope). It shows how to properly use `<h:link>` and which bean scope you should actually be using.