# JSF pass parameters between pages without backend bean

Tags: jsf

I have two JSF pages:

`*categories.jsf*` - here I have links to projects.jsf with URL like
*/projects?id=2*

`*projects.jsf*` - here I want to get id and show specific projects

When I click link on one page, I want to go to the second page with specific parameter. And on the second page get this parameter.
I only found method using **h:commandlink** with backend managed bean. Is it the only way I can do this?

**Edit:**

Existing answers only show using backend beans to pass parameters between pages. My question here - if there is simpler method or no? Without creating beans.

Comment: Is this what you're actually looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/q/8459903

Comment: So it means I need backend bean?

Comment: As per your edit, yes definitely this dupe applies.

Comment: @BalusC I suppose you didn't see my question?(( I ask if this method IS THE ONLY ONE. I know I can use bean for this purpose!

Comment: Beans just provide the requested data? There are indeed different ways, but that all depends on functional requirements. For your particular functional requirement, the dupe applies.