# Passing f param value from one page to another?

Tags: jsf, parameter-passing, jsf-2.2, commandlink

i have a Link in my page the links has a value associated with it , which is dynamically populated by database , the application is in session scope but the param values are not getting updated when passed to new page .

```
<c:forEach var="var" items="#{test.region}">
    <h:commandLink action="#{test.goToPage}" value="#{var}">
        <f:param name="action" value="#{var}" />
    </h:commandLink>
</c:forEach>
```

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Map<String,String> params = fc.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
action = params.get("action"); 
System.out.println("I am sesson"+ action);
```

The value is always comming null

Comment: In your title you said "f param", but an `ui:param` as in your code is not a `f:param`.

Comment: Sorry i copied the wrong code i was my self debugging it and copied it by mistake sorry

Comment: If you want a master-detail approach, I suggest to follow this example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8459903