# JSF bean creates more than once

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, managed-bean, postconstruct, requestscope

When I open jsf page then `catalog bean` creates two times. So why does it happen?
jsf page:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{catalog.products}" var="p">
    <h:column>
        <h:form>
            <h:commandLink action="detail?faces-redirect=true"
                value="#{p.brand} #{p.model}">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{p}"
                    target="#{ph.currentProduct}" />
            </h:commandLink>
        </h:form>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.component.html.HtmlDataTable;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import dataLayer.Dao;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Catalog implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private Dao dao;

    private List<Product> products;
    HtmlDataTable dataTable;

    public Catalog() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        System.out.println("catalog bean created");
        dataTable = new HtmlDataTable();
        products = dao.getShavers();
    }
...
```

Comment: Which server do you use?

Comment: @sinclair JBoss AS 7.1

Comment: I'm just guessing, but I think the second bean is created to handle the following request faster by initializing the bean before the request. Take a look at the Jboss documentation about "bean pooling".

Comment: `HtmlDataTable` property doesn't belong there. Get rid of it. The `<h:commandLink>` there is also strange. I'd expect to see a `<h:link>` there. This is perhaps helpful as to guidelines for this kind of master-detail approach: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8459903 As to the concrete problem, just put a breakpoint in `init()` method and check call stack who/what/why called it.

Comment: @BalusC `HtmlDataTable` property is there for pagination purposes so if you mean the thouble is from that HtmlDataTable then I need to find another pagination aproach.

Comment: It wasn't an answer but a comment. Problem is not visible in information provided so far.

Comment: @BalusC Actualy the reason was in `commandLink's`.  From any page where was `commandLink` to `catalog.xhtml` the catalog bean created twice so replacement with `h:link` solved the issue.  But how actualy the issue is related to `commandLink` behaviour? .

Comment: Because you're sending a redirect after postback which destroys the current request and creates a new request. As the bean is request scoped, it will be affected.

Comment: @BalusC I used `?faces-redirect=true` with `commandLink's` mostly to get right `url's` in browser so when not using redirects the links will remains old so how to preserv right links in this case when using commanLinks without redirect?

Comment: Food for read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-navigate-in-jsf-how-to-make-url-reflect-current-page-and-not-previous-o This is also linked as 1st "See also" link in the duplicate. Try reading them as well, in my answers, they usually already answer spinoff questions :)