# primefaces datatable navigation

Tags: jsf, primefaces, navigation

I have a `p:datatable`, on select i want to navigate to different page. I was able to do it with `<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{users.onUserSelect(userInformation.id)}"/>`

```
public void onUserSelect(long id) {
    System.out.println("user selected" + id);
    try {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("users/user.jsf?id=" + id);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

in the resulting page i want to get some data from db using that ID and display it. So, first of all is this approach ok? If so how/where should i get that ID in the resulting page, using request params? or may be there is some other best practice to achieve what i want?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/q/8459903

Comment: @BalusC thanks, this was exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

In result page:

```
<f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{switchController.id}" />
        <f:viewAction action="#{switchController.loadData}"/>
 </f:metadata>
```