# passing parameter from jsf into an object of a bean

Tags: jsf

i'm trying to pass a value of an id from my jsf page to my bean var called id, wich will be used in another jsf page . Please help ! i tried

```
<f:metadata>
<f:viewParam name="id" value="#{newsBean.idd}" />
</f:metadata>
```

and

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{s.id}" target="#{newsBean.id}"></f:setPropertyActionListener>
```

it doesn't work

Comment: What the issue to pass this ? You can take help from http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/4-ways-to-pass-parameter-from-jsf-page-to-backing-bean/

Comment: You're mixing GET/POST approaches. The abovelinked duplicate answers how to use `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` approach (POST). This duplicate answers how to use `<f:viewParam>` approach (GET): http://stackoverflow.com/q/8459903 Take your pick.