# c:set for inner properties of a bean

Tags: jsf, jstl, nested-properties

Is there a way to set a single property of a property in a bean?

For example, I have an Employee class as a property in my bean `UserAttributeView` and I want to set employeeName property from JSF using `c:set` tag.

```
<c:set value="#{item}" target="#{UserAttributeView}" property="????" />
```

Answer (score 3):

The `target` attribute must represent the bean you'd like to set the property on.

So, given a `#{bean}` with an `employee` property which in turn has `name` property, this should do:

```
<c:set target="#{bean.employee}" property="name" value="#{item}" />
```

Comment: Thank you, it is working partly, means its not throwing any error, but I am getting value as null. My bean is declared as Viewscoped. Is there anything else I need to take care of. I am using it in commandbutton.

Comment: In command button? It looks like you're using the wrong solution for the problem you tried to solve. Is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/q/4994458 Or perhaps this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/8459903 The `<c:set>` can't be used as it runs during view build time (to do initialization), not during pressing the button.