# Passing values from one HTML page to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsf, xhtml

I'm currently working on a online catalogue and need help with a specific feature. I have a page manageCards.xhtml which contains a table, which displays card information (this has been hard-coded). There is a button at the bottom of this page which takes them to a new page addNewCards.xhtml where they can fill in the relevant fields to register a new card.

My question is, is there a way I can transfer the values between these pages and populate a new instance of the same table back on the manageCards.xhtml page, but for the newly registered card? I'm relatively new to both JavaScript and jQuery but I'm sure there's a way I'm not familiar with yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Many thanks

Comment: Post the code, whatever you tried.

Comment: What about php and other cgi

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459903/creating-master-detail-pages-for-entities-how-to-link-them-and-which-bean-scope

Answer (score 1):

You can use localStorage.

When you click the button, before navigating, you can store the data in local storage so that it can be read in the new page.

```
function storeCardInfo(data) {
  localStorage.setItem('cardData', JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

Then on the second page, read that data from localStorage.

```
function getCardInfo() {
   var cardInfo = localStorage.getItem('cardData');
   return JSON.parse(cardInfo);
}
```

Comment: That a way to pass data from one page to the other. When using JSF this solution is somewhat awkward.

Comment: The question appeared to be about Javascript and JQuery based on the second paragraph in the description.