# Right way to use same page for new / edit bean with f:viewParam?

Tags: forms, jsf, jsf-2, jpa-2.0

I've been using JSF for a couple of months. 
My bean Person has a lot of fields (about 50) and some sub-beans (4 Addresses, 2 Contacts..): the related form is big and managed with some ajax actions. I would use that form for "new" Person and also for "edit" Person.

Following [Creating master-detail pages for entities, how to link them and which bean scope to choose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459903/creating-master-detail-pages-for-entities-how-to-link-them-and-which-bean-scope) now I have a form for person.xhtml, a search page *search_p.xhtml* where I choose Person and go to *edit_person.xhtml*.

search_p.xhtml has a list of Person, each person has this link

```
<h:link value="Open" outcome="person">
 <f:param name="id_p" value="#{person.id}"/>
</h:link>
```

person.xhtml contains

```
<f:metadata>
 <f:viewParam name="id_p" value="#{editPerson.person}"
 converter="#{personConverter}"
 converterMessage="Person unknown, please use a link from within the system."
 required="true" requiredMessage="Bad request, please use a link from within the system." />
</f:metadata>
```

PersonConverter has

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class PersonConverter implements Converter {
 public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
  if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) return null; 
  try {
   if(value.equals("new")) return new Person(); //used for link to new
   else {
    Integer id = Integer.valueOf(value);
    return PersonDAO.getById(id.intValue());
   }
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) { throw new ConverterException("Not valid Person ID: " + value, e); }
 }

 @Override    
 public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {        
  if (value == null) return "";
  if (value instanceof Ordine) {
   Integer id = ((Ordine) value).getId();
   return (id != null) ? String.valueOf(id.intValue()) : null;
  } else {
   throw new ConverterException("Not valid Person ID: " + value);}
 }
 }
```

side_menu.xhtml is part of template, here it calls "New Person"

```
<li><h:link value="New" outcome="person">
  <f:param name="id_p" value="new" />
</h:link></li>
```

EditPerson bean is

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class EditPerson implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1768587713177545840L;
    private Person person; 

    public Person getPerson() {return person;}
    public void setPerson(Person person) {this.person = person;}
    public String save() {
        PersonDAO.addOrUpdate(person);
        return "/search_p?faces-redirect=true";
    }
```

So, when in person.xhtml I click on

```
Contact 2
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{editPerson.person.enable_c2}" id="flag_c2">
    <f:ajax event="click" execute="flag_c2" render="div_c2"></f:ajax>
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

a popup appears: 
*serverError: class javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException /include/person/tab_anag.xhtml @372,26 value="#{editPerson.person.enable_f2}": Target Unreachable, 'person' returned null*. PersonConverter has been fired, i suppose because of **f:metadata** is in the page code: can i avoid to call PersonConverter when ajax is fired? I need **f:metadata** only for passing id from search_p page.

Comment: Editing a new entry is the same as editing an existing empty entity, so using one page (with maybe some fields read-only when updating) is the way to go.

Comment: This is effectively a fully new question.

Comment: And your last statement is not correct, you only need the viewparam om page loading and not ajax. Search for that has been asked before

Comment: @Kukeltje thanks for comments. I solved using Omnifaces, so <o:viewParam> with required="#{not facesContext.postback}". In this way every ajax call uses the same object Person instead of creating new one.