# How to invoke a bean action method using a link? The onclick does not work

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, hyperlink, onclick, actionmethod

I'm trying to implement a list of users names which can be rearranged by clicking on *UP* or *DOWN* links.

```
<ul>
    <ui:repeat var="user" value="#{cc.attrs.value}">
        <li>
            #{user.name}
            <h:link outcome = "user" value = "left" onclick="#{accountController.moveDown}">
                <f:param name="id" value = "${user.id}" />
            </h:link>
        </li>

    </ui:repeat>
</ul>
```

The problem here is that it seems that I'm not using the onclick attribute correctly. What is the proper way for doing this?

---

**Edit:** Following your advices I placed all the links in a form:

```
<h:form>
        <ui:repeat value="#{cc.attrs.value}" var = "user">
        <div class = "user">
            <h:commandLink id = "Link1" value = "Up" binding = "#{accountController.ommandLink}" action = "#{accountController.moveUserUp}">
                <f:attribute name = "userId" value = "#{user.id}" />
            </h:commandLink>
            <h:commandLink id = "Link2" value = "Down" binding = "#{accountController.commandLink}" action = "#{accountController.moveUserDown}">
                <f:attribute name = "userId" value = "#{user.id}" />
            </h:commandLink>
            <h:commandLink id = "Link3" value = "Delete" binding = "#{accountController.commandLink}" action = "#{accountController.deleteUser}">
                <f:attribute name = "userId" value = "#{user.id}" />
            </h:commandLink>
    </div>
</h:form>
```

the Managed Bean:

```
private UIComponent commandLink;

public void moveUserUp(){
    Integer userId = (Integer)commandLink.getAttributes().get("userId");
    System.out.println("MOVE TAB LEFT :" + userId);
}

public void moveUserDown(){
    Integer userId = (Integer)commandLink.getAttributes().get("userId");
    System.out.println("MOVE TAB RIGHT: " + userId);
}

public void deleteUser(){
    Integer userId = (Integer)commandLink.getAttributes().get("userId");
    System.out.println("DELETE TAB: " + userId);
}

public UIComponent getCommandLink() {
    return commandLink;
}

public void setCommandLink(UIComponent commandLink) {
    this.commandLink = commandLink;
}
```

The communication between the command Link and the managed bean is working but in the UI only the last commandLink (close action) is displayed.

Comment: What's the functional requirement? Moving up/down items by GET requests? Why GET? This kind of actions are absolutely not idempotent (every identical request has a different response) and should surely not be performed by GET.

Comment: I'm used to request based frameworks and there I was separating everything in GET, POST or AJAX. This is why I chose to take this approach here. I didn't use POST mainly because there is no form there. Just o plain list and some links. What would be a good solution for this problem?

Comment: Even in request/restful based frameworks, non-idempotent actions are supposed to be performed by POST/PUT instead of GET. Or do you really want those move up/down actions to be bookmarkable and searchbot-indexable? (i.e. they are executed everytime when the enduser follows the action URL or a searchbot crawls the action URL). In JSF, `<h:commandXxx>` and `<f:ajax>` components perform a POST. Surely they require a form, how else can a POST request be performed in plain HTML which is what JSF generates after all?

Comment: I updated my question. Can you take a look please? Thank you again!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to invoke a bean action method on click of a link, you need `<h:commandLink>`. This must be enclosed in a `<h:form>`.

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink ... action="#{bean.action}" />
</h:form>
```

```
public String action() {
    // ...

    return "/other.xhtml";
}
```

In JSF, only the [attributes](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/commandLink.html) which interpret the EL expression as a [`MethodExpression`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/el/MethodExpression.html) can be used to declare action methods. All other attributes are interpreted as [`ValueExpression`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/el/ValueExpression.html) and they are immediately executed when the HTML output is generated by JSF. This covers the `onclick` attribute, whose value should actually represent a JavaScript function.

In case you actually want to use a GET link, then move the action method to a `<f:viewAction>` in the target page. This will be invoked on page load of the target page.

```
<h:link ... outcome="/other.xhtml" />
```

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewAction action="#{bean.onload}" />
</f:metadata>
```

```
public void onload() {
    // ...
}
```

#### See also:

- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)
- [How to send form input values and invoke a method in JSF bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681123/how-to-send-form-input-values-and-invoke-a-method-in-jsf-bean)
- [How do I process GET query string URL parameters in backing bean on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724428/how-do-i-process-get-query-string-url-parameters-in-backing-bean-on-page-load/)
- [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-navigate-in-jsf-how-to-make-url-reflect-current-page-and-not-previous-o/)

---

> *Following your advices I placed all the links in a form*
>
> *The communication between the command Link and the managed bean is working but in the UI only the last commandLink (close action) is displayed.*

You should not bind multiple physically different components to one and same bean property. Also the `<f:attribute>` to pass arguments is hacky and not necessary anymore in JSF2. Assuming that you're using a Servlet 3.0 / EL 2.2 container (your question history confirms that you're using Glassfish 3), rather just pass the argument as method argument directly:

```
<h:commandLink id="Link1" value="Up" action="#{accountController.moveUserUp(user)}" />
<h:commandLink id="Link2" value="Down" action="#{accountController.moveUserDown(user)}" />
<h:commandLink id="Link3" value="Delete" action="#{accountController.deleteUser(user)}" />
```

with

```
public void moveUserUp(User user) {
    // ...
}

public void moveUserDown(User user) {
    // ...
}

public void deleteUser(User user) {
    // ...
}
```

#### See also:

- [How does the 'binding' attribute work in JSF? When and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-does-the-binding-attribute-work-in-jsf-when-and-how-should-it-be-used)
- [Invoke direct methods or methods with arguments / variables / parameters in EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284236/invoke-direct-methods-or-methods-with-arguments-variables-parameters-in-el)

Comment: Thank you! It works great. It's even better than what I would have expected. I can see that the changes can be seen right away in the page. No need for me to do a refresh or anything of this kind. Why is that?

Comment: Because you did those changes in the POST action methods.

Comment: Hi again! I'm trying to expand the example I gave here. Is it possible for ajax or post requests to not work properly if there is a GET parameter involved as well? I gave an action parameter which can be either view or settings. If the action parameter is set to settings than I should be able to perform some actions on the user component. The problem is that there is nothing happening when I press up / down / delete.

Comment: Put the bean in the view scope.

Answer (score 3):

The `onclick` attribute is used to invoke JavaScript function (client-side). It is be used when you want to attach a JavaScript click event hanlder.

`"#{accountController.moveDown}"` is a method-expression. And as the name suggests looks like `accountController` is a managed bean.

As the [`h:link` doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/) says:

> javax.el.ValueExpression (must evaluate to java.lang.String)

Can be a value expression that must ultimately evaluate to a string.

> Javascript code executed when a pointer button is clicked over this element.

**Update:**

May be what you are looking for is [`h:commandLink`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/). You can use the `action` attribute to invoke the backing bean method.

Comment: so is there a way to access a backing bean method in the same manner?

Comment: h:commandLink has attributes like action, actionListener with can be used to invoke the managedbean method.

Comment: But for command Link I would have to create a form as well. Is there no other solution for solving this? Some event management of some kind?

Comment: First, form (which helps JSF pass information on which method to invoke) is required to invoke the managedbean method. In your case, one workaround could be to use h:commandLink with a form (but keep it hidden) and click it programmaticaly when the h:link is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

```
I have modified your code, let me know if this is what you are looking at achive

    <h:form>
        <a4j:outputPanel id="userList" ajaxRendered="false">
            <ui:repeat  value="#{manageUser.userList}" var="user">
                <div class="user">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.userId} ---- #{user.userName} ---- " />

                    <a4j:commandLink id="LinkUp" value="Up" execute="@this" 
                        action="#{manageUser.moveUserUp}" limitRender="true" render="userList" >
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{user}" target="#{manageUser.user}" />
                    </a4j:commandLink>

                    <a4j:commandLink id="LinkDown" value="down"
                        action="#{manageUser.moveUserDown}" execute="@this" limitRender="true" render="userList" >
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{user}" target="#{manageUser.user}" />
                    </a4j:commandLink>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </div>
            </ui:repeat>
        </a4j:outputPanel>      
        </h:form>

Managed Beans (ManageUser)


import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean(name="manageUser")
@ViewScoped
public class ManageUser  implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5338764155023244249L;

    private List<UserBean> userList;

    private UserBean user;

    /**
     * @return the user
     */
    public UserBean getUser() {

        return user;
    }

    /**
     * @param user the user to set
     */
    public void setUser(UserBean user) {
        this.user = user;
    }


    /**
     * @return the userList
     */
    public List<UserBean> getUserList() {
        return userList;
    }

    /**
     * @param userList the userList to set
     */
    public void setUserList(List<UserBean> userList) {
        this.userList = userList;
    }

    public ManageUser() {
        UserBean user1= new UserBean();
        user1.setUserId("1");
        user1.setUserName("userName1");

        UserBean user2= new UserBean();
        user2.setUserId("2");
        user2.setUserName("userName2");

        UserBean user3= new UserBean();
        user3.setUserId("3");
        user3.setUserName("userName3");

        userList = new ArrayList<UserBean>();
        userList.add(user1);
        userList.add(user2);
        userList.add(user3);
    }

    public void moveUserDown(){

        if(user !=null){
            int indexObj= userList.indexOf(user);

            if(indexObj < userList.size()-1){
                UserBean tempUser=userList.get(indexObj+1);
                userList.set(indexObj+1, user);
                userList.set(indexObj, tempUser);

            }
        }
    }

    public void moveUserUp(){

        if(user !=null){
            int indexObj= userList.indexOf(user);

            if(indexObj > 0){
                UserBean tempUser=userList.get(indexObj-1);
                userList.set(indexObj-1, user);
                userList.set(indexObj, tempUser);

            }
        }
    }

}

UserBean
import java.io.Serializable;

public class UserBean  implements Serializable {



    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3820279264217591645L;

    private String userName;

    private String userId;

    /**
     * @return the userName
     */
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    /**
     * @param userName the userName to set
     */
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the userId
     */
    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    /**
     * @param userId the userId to set
     */
    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

}
```