# send bean data from one jsf facelet to another

Tags: jsf

I have a table in my jsf application with some data from the database. I have made the id values a link, and my goal is to pass the data from the selected row to another facelet. How can I do this? The href I have is:

```
 <td><a href="editOrDeletePage.xhtml?productid=#{product.id}">#{product.id}</a></td>
```

So the goal is that when the user clicks the link, the editOrDeletePage is displayed, and I want the editOrDeletePage to "ingest" the product id, so that it knows what data to display? How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I process URL parameters on page load using Primefaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724428/how-do-i-process-url-parameters-on-page-load-using-primefaces)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you definetely want to use static links, you may, of course, just read a request parameter from a target page using some kind of event listener

```
<f:event listener="#{bean.preRender}" type="preRenderView" />
```

And read the parameter from request:

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
String productId = (String) facesContext.getExternalContext().
                              getRequestParameterMap().get("productid");
```

But it's not really a JSF way to handle navigation, I belive. You may want to use commandLink or some other way of handling user actions. Or maybe, even better, think of using data table, where a user can choose a row, and you can process selection.

Comment: So the code that you posted in the 2nd block is the body of the preRender() method?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. You can set the productId to a variable and later use it while rendering a page. The acticle linked in BalusC answer has a more complete example