# When to use preRenderView versus viewAction?

Tags: jsf-2, jsf-2.2, prerenderview

When should one use the preRenderView event to initialize data for a page versus using the viewAction? Are they equal in use and do they have the same effect?

**preRenderView Event**

```
<f:metadata>
  <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{myBean.initialize}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

or

**viewAction**

```
<f:metadata>
  <f:viewAction action="#{myBean.initialize}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In practice, they can be used to achieve the same effect, but `viewAction` (new with JSF2.2) comes with the following enhancements:

1. **`onPostback`**: `viewAction` comes with this attribute that allows you to specify whether you want the action to be executed on postback to the same view (that is, on page refresh or button submit etc). It defaults to `false`, so you don't even have to specify it if you don't need to. To achieve the same effect with `preRenderView`, you'll need

   ```
    <f:metadata>
        <f:event type="preRenderView" rendered="#{facesContext.postBack}" listener="#{myBean.initialize}"/>
    </f:metadata>
   ```
2. **`phase`**: this attribute allows you to specify that the action be executed during a specific JSF phase. It defaults to `INVOKE_APPLICATION`, but all the other JSF Phase Ids are valid here.
3. **`if`**: This attribute allows you to supply a value expression that evaluates to a boolean result. The view action will only be executed on the outcome of this expression.
4. **`immediate`**: This attribute now grants the ability for a `viewAction` to be executed during the `APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES` phase (as against the default `INVOKE_APPLICATION` phase), allowing it to behave like a regular `UIComponent`

Overall, the `viewAction` is a cleaner design approach to carrying out view commands.

Comment: The trick with `rendered="..."` with the `<f:event>` tag doesn't work for me (on Wildfly 9.0 with Mojarra 2.2.11). According to the [JSF 2.2 VDL documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/), `<f:event>` doesn't have a `rendered`-attribute.

Comment: It's not documented @MartinHöller, but I have (had, when I wrote this answer) JSF2.2 on GF4, and the tag does present with the `rendered` attribute. Might have been an oversight by the devs

Comment: Maybe the bahavior changed with some minor version, but I tried `rendered="false"` and the method specified via the `listener`-attribute got called every time requested the view.