# What is the purpose of rendered attribute on f:viewAction?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

The description of the `rendered` attribute of `f:viewAction` is not clear in the official [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/f/viewAction.html).

I was thinking that, if it contained an expression that evaluated to false, the `action` expression would not be executed like in the following example:

```
<f:viewAction
    action="#{javax.enterprise.context.conversation.begin()}"
    rendered="#{javax.enterprise.context.conversation.isTransient()}"
/>
```

But the `action` is always executed no matter what the `rendered` attribute evaluates to.

So what is its purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably a victim of the timing of the evaluation of the `rendered` attribute. You're safer using the `if` attribute of the `viewAction` as it's sole purpose is your use case:

```
     <f:viewAction action="#{javax.enterprise.context.conversation.begin()}"
if="#{javax.enterprise.context.conversation.isTransient()}"/>
```

The `if` attribute executes the view action only if it evaluates to `true`, and it's new with JSF2.2

Related:

- [When to use preRenderView versus viewAction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24490152/when-to-use-prerenderview-versus-viewaction/24497007#24497007)

Comment: Thanks, it works! But how could I have guessed about the `if` attribute?! Any idea why this is not documented on the link I provided?

Comment: @Xavier - My guess would be that the `if` attribute might have been a late addition to the tag, and got missed in the documentation generation process