# Invoke f:viewAction conditionally based on f:viewParam

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, viewaction

We have a setting where we have different optional view params passed to JSF pages and subsequent view actions to be processed after the params have been set. A very simple example is shown below:

**page.xhtml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

<f:view>
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="a" value="#{page.a}"/>
        <f:viewAction action="#{page.populateA()}" if="#{not empty page.a}"/>

        <f:viewParam name="b" value="#{page.b}"/>
        <f:viewAction action="#{page.populateB()}"/>
    </f:metadata>

    <h:outputLabel value="#{page.message}"/>
</f:view>
</html>
```

**Page**

```
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@ViewScoped
@Named
public class Page {

    private String a;

    private String b;

    private String message;

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void populateA() {
        this.message = "Param a given: " + this.a;
    }

    public void populateB() {
        if (this.b != null) {
            this.message = "Param b given: " + this.b;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the difference is that the processing of `a` does not work (page.xhtml?a=123), whilst the processing of `b` works like a charm (page.xhtml?b=123) - even though I thought I simply moved the null-check from Java to JSF. In respect of readability I would prefer to omit additional null-checks in Java and have the view param processing fully located in JSF, but how can I tweak the code to make the first scenario work?

**EDIT** According to the accepted answer of [What is the purpose of rendered attribute on f:viewAction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25037251/what-is-the-purpose-of-rendered-attribute-on-fviewaction), `if` works per se so I suspect a wrong execution order (first evaluate the action condition, then apply the values to the model).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `<f:viewAction if>` attribute is basically a renamed `<h:xxx rendered>` attribute (I'll leave in the middle whether that's more clear or not, it has at least a [bug in autogenerated documentation](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/4.0/vdldoc/f/viewaction) as consequence; it lists `rendered` instead of `if`) and has thus exactly the same lifecycle during among others the *Apply Request Values* phase as all other UI components. This phase calls the `UIComponent#decode()` of all UI components in the view. For the [`UIViewAction`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/4.0/apidocs/jakarta/faces/component/uiviewaction), the UI component class behind `<f:viewAction>` tag, the [`decode()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/4.0/apidocs/jakarta/faces/component/uiviewaction#decode(jakarta.faces.context.FacesContext)) is described as follows:

> Take no action if any of the following conditions are true:
>
> - The current request is a postback and the instance has been configured to not operate on postback. See [`isOnPostback()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/4.0/apidocs/jakarta/faces/component/uiviewaction#isOnPostback()).
> - **The condition stated in the `if` property evaluates to false. See [`isRendered()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/4.0/apidocs/jakarta/faces/component/uiviewaction#isRendered())**

So, yes, you're indeed right as to "wrong execution order". During *Apply Request Values* phase it checks the `if` attribute and if it evaluates `false`, then the decode won't take place and the action event won't be queued. See also line 609 of `UIViewAction` [source code](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/blob/4.0.3-RELEASE/impl/src/main/java/jakarta/faces/component/UIViewAction.java#L609) where it tests `isRendered()` inside `decode()` and doesn't proceed if `false`. In your case, the `#{page.a}`, which you're checking in the `<f:viewAction if>`, is only available during *Update Model Values* phase, which is *after* the *Apply Request Values* phase.

You'd like to test something else which is guaranteed to be available during *Apply Request Values* phase. The best candidate would be the actual request parameter itself. All "plain" request parameters are in EL scope available by the [implicit EL object](https://balusc.blogspot.nl/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ImplicitELObjects) `#{param}` which references a [`Map<String, String>`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/4.0/apidocs/jakarta/faces/context/externalcontext#getRequestParameterMap()) with the parameter name as key.

So, all in all, this should do:

```xml
<f:viewParam name="a" value="#{page.a}"/>
<f:viewAction action="#{page.populateA}" if="#{not empty param.a}"/>
```

---

**Update** to solve the unintuitive behavior of `<f:viewAction if>`, JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) will since version 2.2 offer an [`<o:viewAction>`](https://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/viewAction) whose `if` is only evaluated during *Invoke Application* phase, right before the action event is broadcasted. This trick was done by simply extending the `UIViewAction` component and overriding its `broadcast()` and `isRendered()` as below:

```java
@Override
public void broadcast(FacesEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
    if (super.isRendered()) {
        super.broadcast(event);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean isRendered() {
    return !isImmediate() || super.isRendered();
}
```

This allows you to use the tag more intuitively:

```xml
<f:viewParam name="a" value="#{page.a}"/>
<o:viewAction action="#{page.populateA}" if="#{not empty page.a}"/>
```