# Render f:viewAction in some cases

Tags: jsf, nullpointerexception, jsf-2.2

I have a `home` page:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewAction action="#{booksBean.selectBook()}"/>
</f:metadata>

<h:head>
    <title>home</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
 ...
<h:link >
    <h:graphicImage name="images/books/s1.jpg" />
    <f:param name="isbn" value="25413652" />
</h:link>
...
</h:body>
```

When user clicks on link, the `isbn` value has been sent to `booksBean.selectBook()` correctly.

But problem is when user navigates from `login` page to `home` page,

Here is `userBean.login()` :

```
public String login() {
    if (loginSuccessfully) {
        return "home?faces-redirect=true"; // problem
    } else {
          //show error message
    }
}
```

Problem is in mentioned section, when user moves to `home.xhtml` the `booksBean.selectBook()` is called automatically, and since it is null yet, i got `NullPointerException`.

How can i go to `home` page from `login` page without invoking the `booksBean.selectBook()` ?

Comment: By not using a viewAction, perhaps? Why do you think you need a viewAction here?

Comment: @meriton I need it in home `h:link` , how can i send a `GET` parameter in through a  link to a bean method without a `viewAction` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution by not using of `f:viewaction`

```
<h:commandButton value="optional value" action="#{booksBean.selectBook()}">
    <f:param name="isbn" value="25413652"></f:param>
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can selectively invoke a `f:viewAction` by specifying the `if` condition. In your case, it appears you want the action executed on postback only, in which case, you can have:

```
  <f:viewAction action="#{booksBean.selectBook()}" if="#{facesContext.postBack}"/>
```

Related:

- [When to use preRenderView versus viewAction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24490152/when-to-use-prerenderview-versus-viewaction/24497007#24497007)

Comment: This exactly fixed a `NPE` which I got before when a view with a "required" (no attribute set, breaks 2nd AJAX request) parameter was not set. E.g. `/faces/admin/admin_user_edit.xhtml?userId=x` versus  `/faces/admin/admin_user_edit.xhtml`, the 2nd one was triggering that NPE as the `f:viewAction` was triggered but the required property in backing bean was not set (because no parameter specific). Hope this helps some more people. But now my edit form is empty. :-(