# How to deep link from a notification or external email to a specific JSF view?

Tags: java, user-interface, jsf, primefaces, deep-linking

Good day Friends

I have been scouring the internet for suitable examples of how to implement deep linking in JSF 2.3.x+

Doing deep linking with REST endpoints and using some JavaScript UI is trivial. But getting this right in JSF 2.3.x+ with PrimeFaces is not so trivial (at least, the solution seems to be evading me).

At a most basic level, I need to accomplish the following:

1. Application server is WildFly latest running on CentOS latest.
2. Using JSF 2.3+
3. Using latest PrimeFaces.
4. Back end runs on PostrgeSQL 11
5. Based on some user action a notification and email requesting approval is generated.
6. The email and notification (notification icon and panel is implemented within the app itself) is send to the specific person(s).
7. The email and notification must contain a link that deep links into the JSF app so that when the user clicks the link in the email, he / she will land on the login page if not already logged in.
8. Then after proper authentication the user is taken to the exact JSF screen showing the correct state based on what the user needs to approve.

I unfortunately do not have any code to show as my attempts because they do not work, and instead of asking how to fix code that is completely wrong from the start; I request only pointers to a blog or a short hint on how to accomplish deep linking with correct state management in JSF.

Sincerest Thanks

Comment: If you have attempts that do not work, that counts as code. Asking for pointers, blogs or even a short hint is sort of 'off-topic' for Stackoverflow, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. And with JSF it sort of is as trivial as it is with rest. Assuming you do know how to get the right view,  all you need to do is get/process a parameter from the URL, https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=jsf+url+parameter helps here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I process GET query string URL parameters in backing bean on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724428/how-do-i-process-get-query-string-url-parameters-in-backing-bean-on-page-load)

Comment: @Kukeltje thanks, most appreciated.

Comment: @Letholdrus you need to provide an specific doubt here. I'm sorry, but I could take 1 hour to write an answer for the whole process you're requesting (code for the e-mail sending business logic, and so on). It also involves a little about security.. Please, focus ;-)