# How can I obtain a URL parameter?

Tags: java, jsf

I have been trying to obtain the id parameter:

http://localhost/client/edit.xhtml?id=0001

I already tried to obtain the parameter with HttpServletRequest using the next code block, but I obtain > id = 1

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
String urlParams = req.getQueryString();
```

How can I obtain > id = 0001?

Comment: Well, how about `req.getParameter("id")`? Or since you added the JSF tag, make use of JSF's facilities.

Comment: Btw, using `getQueryString()` should return `"id=0001"`- it would not change the query string. If you get a string other than the one you've appended to your url you probably have some url rewriting sitting in between.

Comment: JSF way would be [How do I process GET query string URL parameters in backing bean on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724428/), or is your code part of a servlet class?

Comment: @Thomas you are right. There was a rewriting. Now with urlParams = req.getQueryString() I get 0001. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I process GET query string URL parameters in backing bean on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724428/how-do-i-process-get-query-string-url-parameters-in-backing-bean-on-page-load)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get id you can do this

req.getParameter("id");