# Pass an input value directly as action method argument

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Is there a way to do pass an input value as a action's parameter without using managed properties?

i.e.

```
<h:form>        
    <h:inputText id="input" />  
    <h:commandButton action="#{someBean.doSome(input)}" />  
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's during the form submit already there in the JSF component state. Just bind the input component to the view by `binding` attribute, which will reference an [`UIInput`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html) instance, which in turn has a `getValue()` method for the very purpose of retrieving the input value (so that you can pass it as action method argument):

```
<h:form>        
    <h:inputText ... binding="#{input}" />  
    <h:commandButton ... action="#{someBean.doSome(input.value)}" />  
</h:form>
```

The properness of this approach is however highly questionable and depends on concrete functional requirements. This approach is namely basically tight-coupling the view with the model and therefore considered a bad practice.

#### See also:

- [How to send form input values and invoke a method in JSF bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681123/how-to-send-form-input-values-and-invoke-a-method-in-jsf-bean)
- [How does the 'binding' attribute work in JSF? When and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-does-the-binding-attribute-work-in-jsf-when-and-how-should-it-be-used)