# Get the value for multiple <p:rating> of the list

Tags: jsf, primefaces, rating, uirepeat

I have a list on which I am using `<ui:repeat>`. How can I get the values of `<p:rating>` of multiple selected rating option? When I used `<p:selectManyCheckbox>`, it gives multiple selected values by itself. 
How can I achieve the same in `<ui:repeat>`?

[image]

```
<ui:repeat var="product" value="#{tInterests.categoryList}" >
    <tr>
       <td><h:outputText value="#{product.categoryValue}" styleClass="cellLabelMand"/> 
          <p:rating value="#{product.rating}"  stars="10" cancel="true" /></td>
    </tr>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you faced? Do you mean to say that when you submit the form, you aren't seeing the expected values in `categoryList` in the action/listener method?

Comment: Yeah i am not seeing the values for rating. That is all null

Comment: How can we reproduce your problem when starting from scratch with a completely blank project using most minimal configuration and most recent versions? Everything works for me when I copypaste your code and add/stub the missing obvious parts.

Comment: how did you get the values for Drama, Action and Sports. ?

Comment: Just by submitting the form the usual way, exactly as you would do with your <p:selectManyCheckbox>. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681123/how-to-send-hinputtext-values-and-invoke-a-method-in-jsf-bean