# Bean Validation is not triggered in JSF/Primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, bean-validation

I'm trying to validate some values in my form, but this validation constraints I want to come from some annotations(javax.validation.constraints.*) on a class. I tried everything I can, spend a few hours searching google/stackoverflow - but I get the same thing, it may be that I'm missing something really simple, but still I can't see it

I use Primefaces 5.3, and webspehere8.5(java1.7)

Below is my Bean where I'm going to receive the values.

Please note,I tried a few ways to get this working as I was not sure which one would wokr:

1. Use a holder for my values (see below SearchForm class)
2. Directly in the the bean

   ```
   @ManagedBean
   @SessionScoped
   public class MagicBean implements Serializable {
       private static final long serialVersionUID = -8724952745982557284L;

       SearchForm formValues = new SearchForm();

       public void submitSearchForm() {
           System.out.println("is Ok");
       }
       ....

       @NotNull
       @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$", message = "This is not a valid email")
       private String email;
       ...

   }
   ```

Here is the search form class

```
public class SearchForm {
    ...
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, message = "Name should at least be 3 characters long")
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

And here is how my page looks like

```
<p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />
    <p:messages id="msgs2"/>
        <h:form id="searchParamsForm">
           <p:fieldset widgetVar="searchParamsFormToggle" legend="Search params" toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="500">
                <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5">

                    <h:outputText>Name</h:outputText>
                    <p:inputText id="name" required="true" >#{magicBean.formValues.name}    <!-- notice here I use some other class -->
                    </p:inputText>
                    <p:message id="errorName" for="name" style="color:red"/>

                    <h:outputText>Email</h:outputText>
                    <p:inputText id="email">#{magicBean.email}</p:inputText> <!-- direct from the magic bean -->
                    <p:message id="errorMail" for="email" style="color:red"/>

                    <p:commandButton value="Save" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-check" validateClient="true"/>

                    <p:commandButton value="Search" update="msgs msgs2 errorMail searchParamsForm" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-check" validateClient="true" action="#{magicBean.submitSearchForm}" process="searchParamsForm"  >

                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:fieldset>
        </h:form>
```

And of course here are some params I found I have to set

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.CLIENT_SIDE_VALIDATION</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.TRANSFORM_METADATA</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: only no action? You didn't get any errors?

Comment: your form is submitted right? only problem is validation  not applied?

Comment: yes, I use the Validator in there, and it will find the "ConstraintViolation"s

Comment: it seems it doesn't render the validation elements(this is a theory, I'm not very familiar with this thing)

Comment: Where exactly did you learn that you should declare the input value as body of the input component instead of its `value` attribute? I have never seen that in any JSF tutorial/book/showcase. How to properly bind input values from view to model is demonstrated here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3681123

Comment: usually I use the other form, I think I had this copied from somewhere, but now it works, thanks dude!! please do respond here, I will accept