# Database is not working in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have code:

```
                <p:inputText id="inputNumber value="#{BookSearcher.form.inputNumber}" onkeypress="if(event.which &lt; 48 || event.which &gt; 57 ) if(event.which != 8) return false;" />

                <p:commandButton value="Submit" actionListener="#{BookSearcher.submit}" update="book"/>
                <h:outputText id="book" value="#{BookSearcher.form.book}" ></h:outputText>
```

```
 public void submit(){
   long number;
   number=form.getInputNumber();

   Book book; 
   book = bookService.getBook(number);
   form.setBook(book);
   }
```

I want to input number in box and output book name from database
Ex: input :12084---> out put :Harry Potter
but it's not working and error:`bind => [0]`
If I change code in Bean as `book = bookService.getBook(12084);` it's working.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put all `<h:inputXxx/>` components in a `<h:form>` to bind their value to the Bean. See [How to send form input values and invoke a method in JSF bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681123/how-to-send-form-input-values-and-invoke-a-method-in-jsf-bean)

Comment: How would submit would have been called if the form had been missing?

Comment: Based on the the empty line in the minimal example I assumed it is probably that the form covers only the commandButton and the outputText.

Comment: @b3taa: the example is minimal (maybe too minimal) but not complete... So before 'guessing', always ask for a [mcve]  first (typing [ mcve ] without the spaces is a shortcut). And if the question is basically a duplicate of an existing one, you can vote to close it as a duplicate... Thanks for trying to help out though, appreciated.